# Display divs based on router link in angular?

Tags: angular13

I have created a component which contains 2 divs

component.html

```
<div class="div-one">
//come content
</div>

<div class="div-two">
//come content
</div>
```

I want to display first div while i am on a route /profile/add
and second div while I am on a route  /user/info

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the **official** angular website
https://angular.io/guide/router

```
<ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/first-component" routerLinkActive="active" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">First Component</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/second-component" routerLinkActive="active" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Second Component</a></li>
</ul>
```